# Hadoop-2.7.2 MR job in accepted state

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have configured hadoop-2.7.2 in windows. When i submit a MR job, it works fine. But if i submit multiple MR jobs then only one job runs at a time.

First job is in RUNNING state and all other job in ACCEPTED state even yarn has enough memory (3 GB free out of 6 GB).

But the same works fine in hadoop-2.5.2.

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
 <value>6144</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>256</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>2250</value>
</property>
```

Some one help me to run multiple job in parallel.